# Why does Pandas read csv from file but not from url?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, google-sheets

I'm attempting to read a Google sheet as csv into a Pandas dataframe. My code works fine when read from a file in the directory, but attempting to read from the url causes a KeyError. The code:

```
import pandas as pd 

sheet='https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qGnU-OE4mcVf-Gnc1iINpx2pqH5komEWk1_9shmX6nY/export?format=csv&id=1qGnU-OE4mcVf-Gnc1iINpx2pqH5komEWk1_9shmX6nY'

df1 = pd.read_csv(sheet, engine='python',header=0, delimiter=",", error_bad_lines=False)

to_drop = ['Company Size','Products','SalesRep','BRN potential(y/n)','lat','lon']
df1.drop(to_drop,inplace=True,axis=1) # drop unwanted columns
df = df1.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True) # replace NaN values with empty string

a = []
for x in range(len(df)):
    company     = df.iloc[x,0]
    country     = df.iloc[x,1]
    status      = df.iloc[x,2]
    companyType = df.iloc[x,3]
    address     = df.iloc[x,4]
    url         = df.iloc[x,5]
    email       = df.iloc[x,6]
    phone       = df.iloc[x,7]
    source      = df.iloc[x,8]
    contactedYN = df.iloc[x,9]
    contactDate = df.iloc[x,10]
    notes       = df.iloc[x,11]

    a.append({
        'country':country,
        'company':company, 
        'type'   :companyType, 
        'status' :status, 
        'website':url, 
        'address':address, 
        'phone'  :phone, 
        'email'  :email, 
        'source' :source,
        'contact date' :contactDate,
        'notes'  :notes 
        })

b = pd.DataFrame(a)

b['website'] = b['website'].str.rstrip('/')

print(b.head())
```

The error message looks like this:

```
Skipping line 1281: ',' expected after '"'
Skipping line 1782: ',' expected after '"'
Skipping line 1878: ',' expected after '"'
Skipping line 1879: ',' expected after '"'
Skipping line 1880: ',' expected after '"'
Skipping line 33: Expected 1 fields in line 33, saw 2
Skipping line 34: Expected 1 fields in line 34, saw 2
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "csv-practive.py", line 14, in <module>
    df1.drop(to_drop,inplace=True,axis=1) # drop unwanted columns
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python/3.7.2_2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3940, in drop
    errors=errors)
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python/3.7.2_2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3780, in drop
    obj = obj._drop_axis(labels, axis, level=level, errors=errors)
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python/3.7.2_2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3812, in _drop_axis
    new_axis = axis.drop(labels, errors=errors)
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/python/3.7.2_2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 4964, in drop
    '{} not found in axis'.format(labels[mask]))
KeyError: "['Company Size' 'Products' 'SalesRep' 'BRN potential(y/n)' 'lat' 'lon'] not found in axis"
```

I have tried different encoders (utf-8/latin-1), using the requests library to first download the csv, and cannot figure out why pandas reads perfectly fine from the file but not the url.

Here is the result of print(df1):

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
0                                      <html lang="tr">
1                                                <head>
2                                <meta charset="utf-8">
3       <meta name="google-site-verification" conten...
4       <title>Google E-Tablolar - ücretsiz olarak w...
5                                               <style>
6                                          @font-face {
7                             font-family: 'Open Sans';
8                                   font-style: normal;
9                                     font-weight: 300;
10                                                    }
11                                         @font-face {
12                            font-family: 'Open Sans';
13                                  font-style: normal;
14                                    font-weight: 400;
15                                                    }
16                                             </style>
17                                              <style>
18                    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.1s;
19                     -webkit-animation-name: fontfix;
20                -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
21           -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
22                          -webkit-animation-delay: 0;
23                                                    }
24                         @-webkit-keyframes fontfix {
25                                               from {
26                                          opacity: 1;
27                                                    }
28                                                 to {
29                                          opacity: 1;
...                                                 ...
1616            <script nonce="LhV2p2pyOCXcXw51MT6x1Q">
1617                                       (function(){
1618                  gaia_onLoginSubmit = function() {
1619                                              try {
1620                     gaia.loginAutoRedirect.stop();
1621                                    } catch (err) {
1622        // do not prevent form from being submitted
1623                                                  }
1624                                              try {
1625            document.bg.invoke(function(response) {
1626    document.getElementById('bgresponse').value ...
1627                                                });
1628                                    } catch (err) {
1629    document.getElementById('bgresponse').value ...
1630                                                  }
1631                                       return true;
1632                                                  }
1633    document.getElementById('gaia_loginform').on...
1634                                  var signinButton;
1635    signinButton = document.getElementById('next');
1636                gaia_scrollToElement(signinButton);
1637                                                });
1638                                              })();
1639                                          </script>
1640                                          </script>
1641    <script type="text/javascript" nonce="LhV2p2...
1642    'https:\x2F\x2Faccounts.google.com\x2FPassiv...
1643                                          </script>
1644                                            </body>
1645                                            </html>
```

Comment: Are you sure the separator is `,` because I only see space as separator in your KeyError

Comment: After your `df1 = pd.read_csv()..` you should `print(df1)` to see what it looks like. The error message is telling you that the dataframe does not contain the columns your are specifying.

Comment: Are you sure that Python has authorization to read from the url?

Comment: @Erfan I added 'print(df1)' to the post

Comment: As you can see, its not retrieving the `csv`. You probably have no acces to the data like @micric is suggesting.

Comment: @micric I just switched from "only specific people can access" to "anyone can edit" and it worked...thanks, but how could I do this without giving access to the world?

Comment: @aaronalt you should create a new question for that, as per stackoverflow rules

Comment: @micric cheers, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I thought I had exclusive access but I didn't. Link Sharing was 'OFF'. I just changed it to "anyone with the link - can edit".